# How to set a predefined date on extjsDatepicker isntead of date defaulted to today's date

Tags: date, extjs4

I am using an extJs datepicker but on click of it, it is opening the calendar for the current month,year and date.
I want it to be set to some predefined date Eg : 2099-02-11
How can I achieve that, my code is as below.

```
 {
                    xtype : 'button',
                    text  : 'Select Date...',
                    scope : me,
                    menu  : Ext.create('Ext.menu.DatePicker', {
                        handler : function(dp, date) {
                            var D = Ext.Date;                            
                            me.setTimeSpan(D.add(date, D.HOUR, 8), D.add(date, D.HOUR, 18));
                        },
                        scope   : me
                    })
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Ext.create('Ext.menu.DatePicker', {
      handler : function(dp, date) {
           var D = Ext.Date;                            
           me.setTimeSpan(D.add(date, D.HOUR, 8), D.add(date, D.HOUR, 18));
      },
      value:new Date('2014-01-01') //example date
      scope   : me
 })
```